# Can "Conserve Ink-Splat Sustainably" be completed without firing a shot?

Tags: splatoon-3

The objective for the campaign stage "Conserve Ink-Splat Sustainably" is to reach the end without running out of ink. At the end of the stage, Agent 1 made an interesting remark.

> Agent 1: The Captain's all like, "That was pretty good, but they're still no ME!"

I noticed that the stage didn't seem to have any walls you needed to ink for traversal, which got me thinking: Can you impress the captain by completing "Conserve Ink-Splat Sustainably" without firing a single shot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes (mostly).

You can reach the end of *Conserve Ink-Splat Sustainably* without firing a single shot by dodging projectiles and jumping through enemy ink. If you manage to pull it off you will be awarded 3 power egg canisters and Agents 1, 2, and the Captain will acknowledge your accomplishment.

> Agent 1: Just inkredible! You didn't fire a drop! Wow!
>
> Agent 2: Wanna know what the Captain's saying? "Winning without fighting...now, THAT'S victory!"

The one catch is that you will need to fire a single shot to activate the end goal, but aside from that no ink is needed.

Progress through the first set of enemies by jumping through the ink pool. Walk past the next set of enemies until you reach the self-destructing bomb enemies. You can either run past them or engage then run backwards. Run past the Octobomber then hide around the corner to break line of sight so it stops chasing you. Jump through the right side of the ink pool ahead to avoid the sprinkler. Walk around the outside of the curve to avoid the ink pool. Dodge the octosniper by jumping, then hide in the ink pool. Continue dodging the octosniper and keep not firing ink until you reach the end.